# comparing two unequal length and unequal dimension list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, loops

I have two lists, `a` and `b`:

```
a=[['apple'],['pear'],['grapes'],['cherry'],['mangoes'],['banana']]
b=[['apple',15,14],['orange',30,43],['pear',6,67],['grapes',90,709],['cherry',23,9]]
```

The result I want is:

```
b=[['apple',15,14],['orange',30,43],['pear',6,67],['grapes',90,709],['cherry',23,9],['mangoes',0.0,0.0],['banana',0.0,0.0]]
```

I am trying to compare two unequal length lists and append unique values from one list into another list of unequal dimension.

Comment: Why is `a` a list of lists, and not simply `['apple', 'pear', ..]`? And it seems `b` really wants to be a `dict` like `{'apple': (15, 14), 'orange': (30, 43), ...}` which would make `a` just a (possibly incomplete) list of keys (both actual and desired) for `b`.

Comment: Please include your [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: list 'a' is data imported from some other list which in its original form had multiple cols which have been axed but the list of list status remains. I can reformat the list as ['apple', 'pear', ..] but that would mean one more step. And still i do not know how to get to my desired outcome for list 'b'

Answer (score 0):

First, I would make `a` flat list of strings. If you are getting `a` from somewhere else, you can convert it with

```
a = [k[0] for k in a]
```

Next, I would make `b` a `dict`, again converting if necessary with

```
b = dict((k[0], k[1:]) for k in b)
```

Finally, you just want to augment `b` with new values for keys that are in `a` but not yet in `b`.

```
b.update(dict((k, [0.0,0.0]) for k in a if k not in b))
```

To convert back to a list of lists, use

```
b = [[key] + list(values) for k, values in b.iteritems()]
```

Comment: how to convert 'b' back as list of list as originally required. b will feed into other list or for storing additional data in list format. thanks for the solution, works great but converts the list into dict.